# Get bundle path from c++ without using foundation

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++, chromium-embedded

I am currently developing on a Chromium Embedded framework app.
The project consists of a client and a helper. I need to know the bundle path from the helper, easy just use the methods of foundation.... Well I can't since I can't use foundation in the helper.

The client is a C++ based core wrapped in a objective-c++ cocoa app.

The helper is pure C++.

The two apps share an custom class for process-type-based behaviour ( see code below). The "OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing" method needs to use the bundle path! (Just changing file ending to .mm and importing foundation/cocoa does not work, as soon as i import foundation things turn ugly with a huge amount of errors). How can I get bundle path from C++ without foundation? **This does not work: mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();**

```
namespace client {

// Base class for customizing process-type-based behavior.
class ClientApp : public CefApp {
 public:
  ClientApp();

  enum ProcessType {
    BrowserProcess,
    RendererProcess,
    ZygoteProcess,
    OtherProcess,
  };

  // Determine the process type based on command-line arguments.
  static ProcessType GetProcessType(CefRefPtr<CefCommandLine> command_line);

 protected:
  // Schemes that will be registered with the global cookie manager.
  std::vector<CefString> cookieable_schemes_;

 private:
  // Registers custom schemes. Implemented by cefclient in
  // client_app_delegates_common.cc
  static void RegisterCustomSchemes(CefRefPtr<CefSchemeRegistrar> registrar,
                                    std::vector<CefString>& cookiable_schemes);

  void OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing(const CefString& process_type,
                                    CefRefPtr<CefCommandLine> command_line) OVERRIDE;


  // CefApp methods.
  void OnRegisterCustomSchemes(
      CefRefPtr<CefSchemeRegistrar> registrar) OVERRIDE;

  DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(ClientApp);
};


}  // namespace client

#endif  // CEF_TESTS_CEFCLIENT_COMMON_CLIENT_APP_H_
```

Trying to import cocoa/foundation after renaming to .mm:

[image]

Comment: Foundation is just a C api, just **include** not import the h file normally into c++ should work. If not you can create an objective-c++ wrapper that exports C++ functions instead of Objective-C.

Comment: Had to reset the File Type from c++ to obj-c++ in xcode as well as renaming the files to .mm

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, at worst case you should have one objective C++ file that proxies the functions you need.

Comment: That would actually be nicer since I might target windows later... just replace the "proxie-glue" using #if defined(OS_POSIX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing `Foundation.h` when you mean `#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>`. Foundation is an ObjC API (which is not compatible with C++). Core Foundation is a C API. When you include CoreFoundation, `CFBundleGetMainBundle()` should be fine. Note the `CF` at the start that is indicating it's part of Core Foundation, vs `NS` which indicates Foundation (or AppKit).

There is no need to rename this `.mm`. As long as you use CoreFoundation, it's fine to be a pure C++ file. Just remember that Core Foundation has its own memory management. There is no ARC. You need to remember to `CFRelease` anything you obtained using a function with `Create` or `Copy` in its name (or that you called `CFRetain` on. Full details are in the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000127i).